# Formatting Field In Dao Database - Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this code for a DAO - Database

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlinsert As String
sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO 400_CF_BREAK_LOG ([Number]) Values ('" & rs("[Number]") & "') "
DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlinsert)
```

When I run this, the Number will often be to a large decimal place, implying the need for Round(,2) or Format(, " #.00"). 
However, this code does not function.

```
    sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO 400_CF_BREAK_LOG ([Number]) Values ('" & rs("Format([Number], "#.00")") & "') "
```

Any ideas as to what the code should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO 400_CF_BREAK_LOG ([Number]) Values ('" & Format(rs("[Number]"), "#.00") & "') "
```

Comment: much appreciated!